# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,!=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

So, I tried to use this SQL Server trigger on my C# program:

But I got an error and says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
> The statement has been terminated.'

What should I do about this error?

```sql
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[ComputeTotal] 
ON [dbo].[tblPurchase]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tblPurchase 
    SET VatDiscount = (DiscountedQuantity * (.12*Price)) 
    
    UPDATE tblPurchase 
    SET VatTotal = (DiscountedQuantity * Price) - VatDiscount

    UPDATE tblPurchase 
    SET Discount = DiscountedQuantity * (.20*Price)

    UPDATE tblPurchase 
    SET NormalDiscountTotal = (Price * DiscountedQuantity) - Discount
    
    IF (SELECT VatDiscount FROM tblPurchase) = 0.00
        UPDATE tblPurchase 
        SET Total = (Quantity * Price)

    IF (SELECT VatTotal FROM tblPurchase) > 0.00
        UPDATE tblPurchase 
        SET Total = (VatTotal - (VatTotal * .20))
END
```

Comment: I removed C# / Winforms / Visual Studio tags as the code and problem in question don't seem related in any way to these tags.

Comment: What do you think this `(Select VatDiscount from tblPurchase) = 0.00` is going to go? A table has the possibility to have multiple rows, you are not specifying which row you are interested in... hence the error you are getting, you cannot compare the result of multiple rows to a single scalar.

Comment: If you check the documentation for create trigger in SQL Server you will come across the Inserted and Deleted pseudo tables, for which there is another entire help section in the documentation. This will guide you in how to correctly write a trigger.

Comment: And use set-based operations, thats the most efficient way to use a relational database. I have no idea why, when people come to write triggers, they throw all their set-based query knowledge out the window and start writing procedural code... do the same as you normally would do, construct an update, join on the relevant table (include inserted/deleted as required) and use a where clause to limit etc...

Comment: And if after reading the documentation you still need help writing a trigger, you need to explain what it is intended to do, and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

The specific exception that you are getting can be caused by lines like this:

```
IF (SELECT VatDiscount FROM tblPurchase) = 0.00
```

If there is more than one row in `tblPurchase`, the above SELECT will return more than one value. How do you want to compare these multiple values with 0.00? You didn't tell that to SQL Server, so it raises an error. Instead you could do something like this...

```
IF 0.00 = ALL(SELECT VatDiscount FROM tblPurchase)
```

...or...

```
IF 0.00 = ANY(SELECT VatDiscount FROM tblPurchase)
```

...to avoid the exception, but I don't think this is what you really want either, because the UPDATE underneath the IF will still modify all rows, not just those which satisfy the IF.

Also, it's strange that you are not using `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables. Triggers usually operate on the rows being inserted/updated/deleted, which are accessible through these pseudo-tables.

Note that even if an INSERT statement inserts multiple rows, the trigger will be called only once (ditto for for UPDATE and DELETE). I.e. a trigger can process **multiple rows** in one call, so the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo-tables can contain multiple rows.

In your case, you probably want to apply discounts to the new purchases being inserted, not the old purchases, right? You can do that by joining with `inserted` in the UPDATE statement, similar to this:

```
UPDATE tblPurchase
SET
    VatDiscount = (DiscountedQuantity * (.12*Price))
FROM
    inserted
    JOIN tblPurchase
        ON inserted.PurchaseId = tblPurchase.PurchaseId
```

Etc...

Also, consider if you really need `AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE` trigger. Perhaps just `AFTER INSERT` is enough?

Also, consider merging all these separate UPDATE statements into one. Don't be afraid to put common logic into a common table expression (aka CTE - under WITH clause) as needed. For example, you may first calculate `VatDiscount` in a CTE before assigning it to the field in the table *and* also using it as part of another calculation.